# jQuery and IE8: Form action and submit problem

Tags: php, jquery, forms, internet-explorer-8

I have some code that isn't doing what I want it to in IE8. When you hit the "preview" submit button, a bit of Javascript jumps in and changes the form's action to franchisepreview.php. This sets a session variable so when you go back to the form you won't loose anything. Hitting "Update" or "Insert" goes straight to a query that inserts a franchise.

In IE8 the Javascript isn't jumping in. It submits the form without ever changing the action.

The bit of jQuery I'm using:

The bind:

```
jQuery("#preview").bind("click", changeForm);
```

The function `changeForm`:

```
function changeForm(event)
{
    alert("Before: "+ jQuery("#franchiseform").attr("action"));
    jQuery("#franchiseform").attr("action", "franchisepreview.php");
    alert("After: "+ jQuery("#franchiseform").attr("action"));
    jQuery("#franchiseform").submit();
}
```

Comment: I get the first alert and then nothing.

Comment: so that means the javascript IS doing something. I bet the submit happens before the attr takes effect; try chaining them.

Comment: Nope, that's not it either. The first alert pops up and then nothing happens if the preview `input` is a button. If I make it a submit the first alert pops up and then it submits without changing the action.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try chaining to make sure the attribute is set before the form is submitted:

```
jQuery("#franchiseform").attr("action", "franchisepreview.php").submit();
```

Doesn't look like `.attr()` accepts a callback.

Comment: Chaining is a much more efficient way as well since the DOM is only traversed once P.S - .attr() is not an async type function so a callback is not necessary.